# Setting cookies to httpClient of Asp.Net Core TestServer

Tags: c#, testing, cookies, asp.net-core

I,m testing ASP.NET Core app with TestServer, and there are controllers that require cookie auth. I've created test server instance like this:

```
_testServer = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment(CustomEnvironments.Test)
            .UseContentRoot(currentDirectory)                
            .UseStartup<Web.Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://localhost/"));

ApiClient = _testServer.CreateClient();
```

and now I have to add auth cookie, but it is ignored by server. If the client could be created directly I could pass `HttpClientHandler` to constractor and set `UseCookies` to false, and it works, but I can't access the handler when I get client from test server. Is there a way to add auth cookies to test client?

Comment: Cookies can be set directly on the request when being made

Answer (score 6):

I've found the solution. `TestServer` has method `CreateRequest(string path)`, it returns `RequestBuilder`, which allows to insert cookies to header

Comment: Would love it @alexk if you could post some code about how you did this with the `RequestBuilder`

Answer (score 4):

Using @AlexK's answer for inspiration, combined with information from [a blog post](https://reasoncodeexample.com/2016/08/29/how-to-keep-things-tidy-when-using-asp-net-core-testserver/) (as an aside, this post goes into a lot of other useful details when dealing with other issues when sending requests to the test server), here is one way of getting cookies to work with the `TestServer` using `CreateRequest(string path)` based on what I used for my own project.

```cs
public class TestWebEnvironment : IDisposable
{
    private TestServer Server { get; }
    private CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; }

    public TestWebEnvironment()
    {
        var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment("Test")
            .UseStartup<TestWebStartup>();

        Server = new TestServer(builder);
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    }

    private RequestBuilder BuildRequest(string url)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(Server.BaseAddress, url);
        var builder = Server.CreateRequest(url);

        var cookieHeader = CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(uri);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cookieHeader))
        {
            builder.AddHeader(HeaderNames.Cookie, cookieHeader);
        }

        return builder;
    }

    private void UpdateCookies(string url, HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        if (response.Headers.Contains(HeaderNames.SetCookie))
        {
            var uri = new Uri(Server.BaseAddress, url);
            var cookies = response.Headers.GetValues(HeaderNames.SetCookie);
            foreach (var cookie in cookies)
            {
                CookieContainer.SetCookies(uri, cookie);
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<string> GetAsync(string url)
    {
        using (var response = await BuildRequest(url).GetAsync())
        {
            UpdateCookies(url, response);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }

    public async Task<string> PostAsync(string url, HttpContent content)
    {
        var builder = BuildRequest(url);
        builder.And(request => request.Content = content);
        using (var response = await builder.PostAsync())
        {
            UpdateCookies(url, response);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Server.Dispose();
    }
}
```